# Is the issue with logging in due to cPanel hosting or the Passport.js code?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, cpanel

I have created a basic login, register, and home pages. They work perfectly on my local machine. However, when I upload the website to a hosting service (in this case, Namecheap) and try to log in using the same credentials, it keeps saying that the password is incorrect. What could be causing this issue? when clear i have the right password,

```
here is the password Passport cong
function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById) {
  const authenticateUser = (email, password, done) => {
    const query = 'SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE email = ?';
    connection.query(query, [email], (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }

      if (results.length === 0) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'No user with that email' });
      }

      const user = results[0];

      if (password === user.password) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' });
      }
    });
  }

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, authenticateUser));

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    if (!user || !user.iduser_data) {
      return done(new Error('User object does not have an "iduser_data" property'));
    }
    done(null, user.iduser_data);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    const query = 'SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE iduser_data = ?';
    connection.query(query, [id], (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }

      if (results.length === 0) {
        return done(null, false);
      }

      const user = results[0];
      done(null, user);
    });
  });
}


this is my app.post('/register', checkNotAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const query = 'INSERT INTO user_data (name, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
    await connection.query(query, [req.body.name, req.body.email, req.body.password]);
    res.redirect('/login');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.redirect('/register');
  }
});

app.get('/login', checkNotAuthenticated, (req,res) =>{
  res.render('login.ejs')
})


app.post("/login", checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      req.flash("error", info.message);
      return res.render("login.ejs"); // Render the login template with error message
    }
    req.logIn(user, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return next(err);
      }
      return res.redirect("/home.html");
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```